# What does OS Stack mean?

Tags: united-kingdom, career

"Strong OS Stack Knowledge" is listed as a required skill on a job specification I am interested in. I haven't come across this term before. It may be important to note that I live in the UK and I think OS may either mean Operating System, Open Source or Ordnance Survey.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OS* probably refers to Open Source software

*Stack* refers to a set of software.